# DriverClass not found for database:aurora when export postgresql to S3

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline, amazon-aurora

I try to export Aurora PostgreSQL to S3 through aws data pipeline. However, I got this error: `DriverClass not found for database:aurora`

```
amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: Error copying record at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.processAll(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:65) at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.runActivity(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:35) at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.CopyActivity.runActivity(CopyActivity.java:22) at amazonaws.datapipeline.objects.AbstractActivity.run(AbstractActivity.java:16) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeRemoteRunner(TaskPoller.java:136) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeTask(TaskPoller.java:105) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller$1.run(TaskPoller.java:81) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.executeWork(PollWorker.java:76) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.run(PollWorker.java:53) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: DriverClass not found for database:aurora at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.database.RdsHelper.getDriverClass(RdsHelper.java:24) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getRdsDatabaseConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:151) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:73) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnectionWithCredentials(ConnectionFactory.java:278) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.createConnection(SqlDataNode.java:100) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.getConnection(SqlDataNode.java:94) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.prepareStatement(SqlDataNode.java:162) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlInputConnector.open(SqlInputConnector.java:48) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlInputConnector.<init>(SqlInputConnector.java:25) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.getInputConnector(SqlDataNode.java:79) at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.processAll(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:47)
```

The data pipeline node configuration as below

- type: RdsDatabase
- Jdbc Driver Jar Uri: S3Url

The value of `S3Url` is the postgresql driver downloaded from this page https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html and upload to fixed S3 location.

According to the above error message, the postgresql driver cannot be found. Where this postgresql jdbc driver could be found? or is there any wrong configuration in datapipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Issue was resolved after change the postgresql connection node as following

- Type: JdbcDatabase
- ConnectionString: jdbc:postgresql://.....
- Jdbc Driver Class: org.postgresql.Driver